# fs.existsSync is not a function error when declare edge-js

Tags: node.js, typescript

I worked as follows.

1. npx create-react-app print --template typescript
2. yarn add node-js
3. declare edge-js variable

It's a simple task, but I'm asking because there's an error.
error message is,

```
TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:377:243
```

**Here is my App.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

var fs = require('fs');
var edge = require('edge-js');

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I just put this two code

```
var fs = require('fs');
var edge = require('edge-js');
```

Did I set it up wrong? Please let me know if there is anything I need to add.

Comment: `fs` is a NodeJS FileSystem API and you seem to be using it in a Browser where it won't be available.

Comment: @hariom actually, I make electron app, so I  try this.

Comment: @PolarisNation Have you enabled node on the render process?